# regexp for [nn.nn] or [nn] with corrected groupping

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a regexp to work with datatypes that are presented to me as strings,
there are 2 possible formats:

1. string[nmin..nmax]
2. string[nmax]

where nmin and nmax are some numbers.

I constructed regexp that works for me, but I want to find a way to do it better

```
\[(\d+)(\.{2})?(\d+)?\]
```

What I don't like:

1. I put dots into separate group, but I don't need them as a group.
2. nmax is always present, but depending on a pattern it will be in group 1 or 3. I there a way to always get it in the same group?

Comment: I think I got second part, it was easy: `\[(\d+)?(.{2})?(\d+)\]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `nmax` to be always in the same group you can use

```
\[(?:(\d+)\.{2})?(\d+)]
```

`(?:...)` is a non capturing group, we use it to make the `nmin..` matching construct, `(\d+)\.{2}`, optional.

But even if it is optional, the capturing group index is incremented: `nmax` will always be in group 2, `nmin` (when present) always in group 1. See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/rK5oF6).

Answer (score 3):

You can use non-capturing group in Python for dots: `\[(\d+)??(?:\.{2})?(\d+)\]`.

For `nmin` and `nmax` you can use named groups which will solve second question too.

Comment: solves part 1 of the question. combined with @vav solution for part 2 
 `\[(\d+)?(?:\.{2})?(\d+)\]`

Comment: Thanks! I changed an answer.

Comment: I learned about non-capturing groups, but I can't find how to name my groups. How you do that? is it `\1, \2`?

Comment: `\[(?P<nmin>\d+)?(?:\.{2})?(?P<nmax>\d+)\]`. You can access dictionary of named groups with `MatchObject.groupdict()` or with `MatchObject.group()`

Comment: Be careful, see [what happens](http://regex101.com/r/mL5zD9) when you try it on a two digit number like `[56]`...

Comment: Thanks! Then either @Robin's solution or non-greedy variant. I edited the answer.

Comment: That's a funny fix :)

Answer (score 0):

the regex you want would be:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'\w+\[(?P=min\d+)(?:\.\.(?P=max\d+))?\]')
>>> r.match('aaa[12]').groups()
(u'12', None)
>>> r.match('aaa[12..13]').groups()
(u'12', u'13')
```

and here's the [NFA](https://www.debuggex.com/r/05IR8VPWsxwnwprb) matching that regex:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

and here's the [NFA](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Yt6ddhOKfLGQWQ4F) matching *your* regex:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

which does not match what you said you want, as you're not matching the string part preceding the brackets. So it only matches `[12]` or `[13..14]` but not `xxx[12]` or `aaa[13..14]`

And finally, here's an example using capturing groups:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'\w+\[(?P<nmin>\d+)(?:\.\.(?P<nmax>\d+))?\]')
>>> r.match('aoeu[12]').groupdict()
{'nmax': None, 'nmin': '12'}
>>> r.match('aoeu[12..13]').groupdict()
{'nmax': '13', 'nmin': '12'}
```

Comment: You should escape brackets `[]`, this way they are considered as RE group.

Comment: I messed the paste, sorry, fixed now